# php @mail is not sending mail

Tags: smtp, php, whm

my php mail function was working fine and sending mail just fine but since past few days it is not sending any emails. i have tested following from whm,php form, cpanel webmail and these are my observations

when i used cpanel webmail to send emails to my gmail account it got delivered instantly

when i used php simple form to send email it is not delivered then i thought gmail spam filter might be rejecting mails then i checked the whatismyipaddress tool to check whether server ip is marked as spam it showed all green.then i tried for other hotmail and few other id but the mail through php form did not got delivered. then i checked my php.ini file and its absolutely fine and then i checked whm mail delivery reports(here that email was not appearing) and queue manager(that email was not appearing) and even mail troubleshooter it was green when checked.

i disabled spamassis of whm then also mail was not delivered.where it is going  or where is the problem can anyone give some light

mail.php

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
     <head>
 <title>Send Anonymous Email</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 </head>

  <body>
<form name="SAE" method="post" action="send.php">
   <br>To Email: </br>
   <br><input name="toemail" type="text" id="toemail" value=""></br>
<br>Subject: </br>
  <br><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" value=""></br>
  <br>Message:</br>
 <br> <textarea cols="50" rows="7" name="message"></textarea></br>
<br><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send!"></br>

 </form>
   <p>Powered by <a href="http://asian.sc">Anonymous Email Sender</a></p>
 </body></html>
```

send.php

```
  <?php 



  $toemail = $_POST['toemail']; 
  $subject = $_POST['subject']; 
  $message = $_POST['message']; 

  mail($toemail, '$subject (Sent Anonymously)', "Hello, 
   The following is an anonymous email. 

  $message 

   Powered by http://asian.sc - Anonymous Email Sender", 'From: '.$email); 

      echo "Thank you, $name<br>Message sent to $toemail with the following information:</br>Subject: $subject</br>Message: $message</br><p>Powered by <a href=\"http://asian.sc\">Anonymous Email Sender</a></p>";?>
```

sorry i forgot to mention that i checked log file for errors but that email was not there

Comment: Why don't you share your code here,and we can take a look

Comment: Post code, check your mail log, etc. Need to do a bit more digging before we can help you.

Comment: @PHPNooB code updated please check

Comment: @datasage code updated please check

Comment: "Anonymous email" scripts are frequently abused to send spam. Please don't write or deploy them.

Comment: Your message body contains a multiline string.  Your best bet is to use a HEREDOC to prevent it from being mis-interpreted.

Comment: @GigaWatt i used this script just to check wheter php mail is working or not

Comment: @duskwuff i used this script just to check wheter php mail is working or not

Comment: @james: If you're just testing, why is there a bunch of text about "anonymous email" all over it? Please don't lie to us. You're not very good at it.

Comment: @duskwuff i like your words that i am not very good in lying i searched in internet for simple php mail script and uploaded it for testing. my website is way2enjoy.com when any users add other users php mail function sends email but not its not sending so i am worried what is the problem.hope i have clarified\

Answer (score 3):

This is an attempt of the sendmail to stop sending mail with custom From Headers.

A quick fix is to use an SMTP server to send mail through ( I advice, using a GMAIL account as it is whitelisted in all most all cases.)

Sending emails through SMTP Server
[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)